# Suppress unused property warning in Typescript for individual line

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to let my code compile with ts-node even if there is unused property warnings in one line of my `.ts` file *without* setting `"noUnusedLocals": false` in my `tsconfig.json` file?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Since TypeScript 2.6 you can suppress errors with `// @ts-ignore`.

> A `// @ts-ignore` comment suppresses all errors that originate on the following line. It is recommended practice to have the remainder of the comment following @ts-ignore explain which error is being suppressed.
>
> Please note that this comment only suppresses the error reporting, and we recommend you use this comments very sparingly.

[source (release notes TypeScript 2.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments)

If the error is an tslint error then you can disable them with

```
// tslint:disable-next-line
```

See https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/ for more information.

Comment: FYI - my eslint is recommending to use `// @ts-expect-error` in preference to ignore

Comment: @charles-allen your comment should be the answer. If you'll make an answer, I'll vote for it!

Answer (score 32):

It is now possible to use `_` for unused params.

```
function myFunc(_, b: string) {}
function otherFunc(_, _1, c: string) {} // multiple unsused
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9458

Answer (score 5):

For me, this works to suppress an "unused variable" warning in a React project:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```